# Translating curl to httparty request in ruby

Tags: rails-api, httparty

I can successfully run the following curl command:

```
curl my_interesting-api.herokuapp.com/ -H "Authorization: Token token=6bb4f31b5de728xxxxx360b3896"
```

I am attempting to convert this to a ruby script as follows:

```
require 'httparty'

url = 'my_interesting-api.herokuapp.com/'
response = HTTParty.get(url, 
  headers: {
    "Authorization: Token token" => "6bb4f31b5de728xxxxx360b3896"
  }
)
puts response.inspect
```

I get the follow response in the console with I run this script:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7f881d04cc28 parsed_response="HTTP Token: Access denied.\n", @response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["Cowboy"], "date"=>["Thu, 10 May 2018 17:24:50 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"], "www-authenticate"=>["Token realm=\"Application\""], "content-type"=>["text/plain; charset=utf-8"], "cache-control"=>["no-cache"], "x-request-id"=>["1fd7115d-497d-439d-af4f-49cb3d28b61f"], "x-runtime"=>["0.002321"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], "via"=>["1.1 vegur"]}>
```

Also tried:

```
headers: {
        "Authorization" => "6bb4f31b5de728xxxxx360b3896"
      }
```

...and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Played musical chairs with the headers & quotes until I figured it out.

```
require 'httparty'

url = 'my_interesting-api.herokuapp.com/'

response = HTTParty.get(url,
    :headers => { "Authorization" => 'Token token="6bb4f31b5de728xxxxx360b3896"'})

puts response.inspect
```